# addEventListener with function call inside of anonymous callback attaches extra event?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, element

What is the difference between use my function inside of addEventListener's anonymous callback and use my function as addEventListener's callback?

Example code:

```
 /* function call inside of anonymous callback 
    => Attaches extra event
 */
 childEl.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
   handler(e);
 });

 /* function as callback 
    => Only attaches one event
 */   
 childEl.addEventListener('click',handler);
```

Cause I don't get it, why calling my function inside of addEventListener's anonymous callback attaches extra event to my element and if I use function as callback, it'll only attach one event to my element...

(More info about my problem at the end)

js

```
const mainContainerEl = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const btnEl = document.querySelector('button');

console.log(mainContainerEl);
console.log(btnEl);

const handler = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
};


btnEl.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      const newSpanEl = document.createElement('span');
      newSpanEl.textContent = i;
      mainContainerEl.append(newSpanEl);
  }
  if(mainContainerEl.children){
    const mainContainerElChildren = [...mainContainerEl.children];
    mainContainerElChildren.forEach((childEl)=>{

      /* function call inside of anonymous callback 
         => Attaches extra event
      */
      childEl.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        handler(e);
      });

     /* function as callback 
        => Only attaches one event
     */  
     childEl.addEventListener('click',handler);

    });
  }
});
```

html & css

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid darkBlue;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

--------------------------------------------------

<body>
    <div class="main-container"></div>
    <button>Click to add elements</button>
    <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

What my code is doing is, when the user clicked the button, it will append five new elements to main-container element(will not remove any previous elements) and it will add click event listener to all children elements inside of main-container element(so previous elements will also add event listener again), so for example **(using the function call inside of anonymous callback way)** if I click the button 3 times, I should get 15 elements on the page and first 5 elements, each of element will have 3 event listener attach to it and second 5 elements, each of element should have 2 event listener attach to it and the recent 5 elements,each of the element should only have 1 event listener attach to it but **how come when I use "function as callback" way to add event listener, it doesn't matter how many times I clicked the button, it will only add 1 event listener to each of the child inside of main-container element?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here, MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#multiple_identical_event_listeners) .

```
handler === handler
```

is true, but

```
((e) => {console.log(e.target.textContent);}) === ((e) =>{console.log(e.target.textContent);})
```

is false so that handler is not added twice or more while anonymous functions are added multiple times.

UPDATE: If you want to update your event listener removing anonymous function previously attached, first you save it to your element,

```
my_element.my_func = (e) => {...};
my_element.addEventListener('click', my_element.my_func);
```

then remove the function and attach another new one;

```
my_element.removeEventListener('click', my_element.my_func);
my_element.my_func = (e) => {...}; // New definition
my_element.addEventListener('click', my_element.my_func);
```

Of course, there are a lot of ways to do the same and the above is just one of them.

UPDATE: Following suggestion by @JaffaTheCake;

```
btnEl.addEventListener('click',(function(){
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
      const newSpanEl = document.createElement('span');
      newSpanEl.textContent = i;
      mainContainerEl.append(newSpanEl);
    }
    if(mainContainerEl.children){
      const mainContainerElChildren = [...mainContainerEl.children];
      mainContainerElChildren.forEach((childEl)=>{
        if (this.wm.get(childEl)) {
          childEl.removeEventListener('click', this.wm.get(childEl));
        }
        // Anonymous function of your choice
        this.wm.set(childEl, (e)=>{handler(e);});
        childEl.addEventListener('click', this.wm.get(childEl));
      });
    }
  }).bind({wm: new WeakMap()}) // bind cannot be used with arrow functions
);
```

Anyway, it's deviating from your original question...

Comment: oh~but because I need to pass params in to the event handler so I have to use anonymous function to call my handler function, is there a way I can use anonymous function but without attach multiple events to an element?

Comment: You can save your anonymous function to elements and refer to them to be deleted by removeEventListener. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't add properties to object types that you don't own (`my_func` in this case). Instead, if you want to associate something with another object, use a `WeakMap` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap.

You should also remove the reference to the callback once you're done with it, so memory can be collected.